# Most pythonic way to call a list of functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of functions, like so:

```
def foo(a, b):
    # do stuff
    return True # or False

def bar(c):
    # do stuff
    return False # or True

def baz(d, e, f):
    # do stuff
    return True # or False
```

and I want to call each of them in turn, and only proceed to the next one if the previous one returns `True`, like so:

```
if foo(1, 2):
    if bar(3):
        if baz(4, 5, 6):
            print("Success!")
```

Now, I know that if all of my functions accepted the same arguments, I could do something like:

```
steps = [foo, bar, baz]
if all(func(*args) for func in steps):
    print("Success!")
```

because `all` would short-circuit as soon as it reaches a `False` return value. However, they do not all accept the same arguments.

What would the cleanest way to achieve this?

Edit: Thanks for the suggestions about zipping the args. What about a more general case where each function returns some value, and I want to use the return value of the previous function, whatever it may be, to decide whether or not I run the next function? Each function may also require as arguments some of the return values of the previous functions.

Comment: then do `arguments = [[1, 2], [3], [4, 5]]` and then `all(func(*args) for func, args in zip(steps, arguments))`

Comment: You could use a variant of your `all` method if you had a list of the argument sets and you zipped it together with the functions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I updated my question since I realized I slightly oversimplified my situation in my original post.

Comment: Your question is rapidly becoming too broad, you should ask about the exact problem you're trying to solve

Comment: Given there were sevearl answers already to your question you would have been better to just ask a new question

Comment: Your edit makes a general solution difficult, there are too many variations possible.

Comment: I think with the edit, the answer is that you should just write it in the most naive way possible.  Put it all in a function, assign the output of each function to a value and then test those outputs for early `return`s.

Answer (score 6):

The `and` operator also short-circuits, so you can do:

```
if foo(1, 2) and bar(3) and baz(4, 5, 6):
    print("Success")
```

If you want a more general way, you can make a list of lambdas.

```
steps = [
    lambda: foo(1, 2), 
    lambda: bar(3), 
    lambda: baz(4, 5, 6)
]
if all(f() for f in steps):
    print("Success")
```

or a list of tuples:

```
steps = [
    (foo, (1, 2)), 
    (bar, (3)), 
    (baz, (4, 5, 6))
]
if all(f(*args) for f, args in steps):
    print("Success")
```

Comment: `and` is by far the cleanest and easiest to me....nice job

Comment: The last example should be the first :)

Comment: Whilst i've already upvoted this, the op's edit invalidates your answer (and others)

Answer (score 3):

Use `all` like this:

```
steps = [foo, bar, baz]
arguments = [[1, 2], [3], [4, 5, 6]]
if all(func(*args) for func, args in zip(steps, arguments)):
    print("Success!")
```

Comment: I dislike separating the functions from the arguments like this, it's too easy for them to get out of sync.

Comment: You could just make them a dictionary, with the function as a key and args as the value

Comment: @martineau fixed it.

Comment: @Barmar I wanted the op to do minimal changes to his code.

Comment: @Sayse Dictionaries aren't ordered, and it won't work if you want to call the same function twice with different arguments.

Comment: @Sayse Pre Python 3.7 there is no guarantee the functions will be called in the correct order if dict was used

Comment: @both - good point

Comment: @mamun The OP's code has the function names close to the arguments, so do all my solutions. Yours is more changes, since they're in separate lists.

Comment: @Barmar: If one wants an ordered dictionary, there's always `collections.OrderedDict` which is supported from Python 2.7 onwards.

Comment: @Barmar  Why are you telling everyone dictionaries aren't ordered?  They have been ordered for *years* now.

Comment: @wim I didn't know this changed in 3.7. But many people are still using 3.6 (and even 2.x), so that's a bit extreme to say they've been ordered for years.

Comment: I would always just assume dictionary is unordered because in my experience most people / company are not even close to running near latest release, and also in most other languages thats also true

Comment: @Chris: With `OrderedDict` there would be much less need to have a recent version.

Comment: @martineau yeah i totally agree and its quite clear when using it that it maintains the order. I just think by default my brain see's a normal dict / hash in any language and i just assume unordered

Answer (score 3):

Functions are hashable objects, so you can use them as keys of dicts.

```
funcs = {
    foo: (1, 2),
    bar: (3,),
    baz: (4, 5, 6),
}
```

This is a little cleaner than separate lists of functions and arguments, because it prevents the lists from falling out of sync.

Now just use `all`:

```
if all(f(*args) for f, args in funcs.items()):
    print("Success!")
```

Dictionaries are ordered in the current version of Python (3.8.0), as well as the previous minor version (3.7.x). If you use an older version of the language (< 3.7), you may still do the same with a [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

This approach does not work if you want to call the same function more than once, because dictionary keys must be unique.  In this case you should use a list of pairs instead:

```
steps = [
    (foo, (1, 2)),
    (bar, (3,)),
    (baz, (4, 5, 6)),
    (foo, (7, 8)),
]
```

Comment: Dictionaries aren't ordered.

Comment: But the order is not guaranteed here right?

Comment: @Barmar They are ordered in Python >= 3.7

Comment: @shmth Order is guaranteed in Python >= 3.7

Comment: ``dict`` is de-facto ordered since 3.6 already -- CPython added insertion-order in 3.6 and PyPy had it since 2.7.