# Python - call function with arguments based on dictionary lookup

Tags: python

I have a bunch of functions that generate some sort of test data and I would like to call them based on a probability distribution I specify.

```
import numpy as np
def one():
    print('one')

def two():
    print('two')

def three():
    print('three')

def four():
    print('four')

def five():
    print('five')

funcs = {
    1: one, 2: two, 3: three, 4: four, 5: five
}
distribution = [0.1, 0.15, 0.15, 0.2, 0.4]
my_keys = list(funcs.keys())
choice = np.random.choice(my_keys, 1, p=distribution)[0]
funcs[choice]()
```

This picks a key from `funcs` according to the distribution specified and then executes the corresponding function, and this works as-is.

Now the problem is that each function has a different set of arguments. For example, the function `one()` could have an argument that makes it have to be called as `one(foo)` while `two` needs to be called as `two(blah)` and so on.

How can I accomplish this? I would rather not go the route of having `np.random.choice` return a key and then I use an if-then-else construct to call the functions with the correct parameters as that seems pretty un-pythonic.

TIA.

Comment: Do you know the arguments ahead of time, or only after doing the lookup?

Comment: I would know them ahead of time, as I have the function definitions.

Comment: I mean do you have data to be passed as arguments ahead of time?

Comment: I think that you can create a dictionary also for your params, based on your function. Something like `{"one": params1, "two": params2, etc}`

Comment: Check out [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) if you need to bind arguments to a function. Otherwise, I'd recommend giving an example of some parameter you want to pass to the selected function

Comment: If you have the data ahead of time, I'd usigg `functools.partial` and partially apply the functions first.

Comment: @Carcigenicate yes, depending on the function, I'm passing either a distribution or dictionary lookup

Comment: You could use lambdas in the dictionary. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58549042/most-pythonic-way-to-call-a-list-of-functions/58549091#58549091 for something similar.

Comment: What does this have to do with `numpy`? The way you're selecting the random choice is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lambdas to provide the arguments.

```
def one(a):
    print('one' + a)

def two(a, b):
    print('two' + str(a + b))

def three():
    print('three')

def four(x):
    print('four' + str(x))

def five():
    print('five')

funcs = {
    1: lambda: one("abc"), 
    2: lambda: two(10, 25), 
    3: three, 
    4: lambda: four(15), 
    5: five
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising. Removed the numpy tag

Comment: Question - each of the functions should return a dataset - how would this work with a lambda? So `def one(a): return('one' + a)` should be returned

Comment: If it needs to return a dataset then it needs to use pandas/numpy functions. My code was just simple examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lambdas. If the function can't be transformed into a lambda, you can store the functions like variables.

```
def run_thing():
    # your code here...
    return

def another_func():
    # your code here
    return

x = run_thing
y = another_func
funcs = {0: x, 1: y}

# runs the method run_thing
func[0]()
#runs the method another_func
func[1]()
```

I put the return just to make this more understable, but it's not necessary.